Water level in pipe higher than surrounding body of water
I had a question about water pressures and level. We've recently drilled a near vertical hole underground 130m deep by 400mm in Dia into flooded lower underground workings as part of a de-watering program. The drill hole is located about 2m above the flooded area and broke through into the lower workings. What we've noticed though is the water in the drill hole is sitting higher than the actual water level of the mine, it sits at the top of the hole. Why is that?

This question might be better on https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Is the water in the mine artesian water or rainwater? Is the rock permeable?

To get equilibrium, the water in the pipe needs to create an equal pressure at the lower end of the pipe as the mix of water and soil outside the pipe. The soil and water mix has a greater density that water alone, so a higher level of water is needed to compensate that.

You may have drilled into an artesian formation, or another possibility is that the density of the water in the pipe differs from the average density of the water in the fluids through the sequence of formations that you drilled.  This would be due to different concentrations of dissolved solids.
